# How can I save multiple files from an NSData object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I have a zip file, which gets extracted using Objective-Zip. The extracted contents then get put into an NSData object. I want to save the contents into the apps Documents folder. The problem is these are multiple files, and writeToFile:atomically: saves the contents of the zip into one file.

Any ideas? The other question I saw just said to use ZipArchive.

I need help fast, because the app needs to be finished by the end of my work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use ZipArchive:

```
ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
NSData *Data = [NSData  dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; // here url is your zip url
NSArray *documentPathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirString = [documentPathArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.zip"];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSError *writeError = nil;
[Data writeToURL: fileURL options:0 error:&writeError];
if( writeError) {
   NSLog(@" Error in writing file %@' : \n %@ ", filePath , writeError );
   return;
}
if( [za UnzipOpenFile:filePath] )
{

    BOOL ret = [za UnzipFileTo:documentsDirz overWrite:YES];
    if( NO==ret )
     {
      NSLog(@"NO");
    }
    [za UnzipCloseFile];
}
```

[for more info](http://www.hindsightlabs.com/blog/2010/12/23/reading-and-writing-zip-files-on-the-iphone/)

Comment: I tried (and will try again now), but I couldn't get it working. I'll see if I can get it to work this time.

Comment: your zip file is password protected? then use -(BOOL) UnzipOpenFile:(NSString*) zipFile Password:(NSString*) password; method

Comment: It fails when I try to build. I get `"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZipArchive", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7`

Comment: Fixed it. What happened was I was opening the ZipArchive folder, selecting it and dragging it into Xcode. What you need to do is drag the folder (don't open it) into Xcode, and make sure you select Create groups for any added folders.